# Записать json в массив

Tags: java, android, json

Требуется добавить `JSONObject` в массив `products` используя `org.json`

```
  {  
   "products":[  
      {  
         "id":"001.427.40",
         "name_product":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044b\u043d\u044f",
         "shirina":260.0,
         "dlina":150.0,
         "image":"",
         "comments":""
      },
      {  
         "id":"001.635.58",
         "name_product":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044b\u043d\u044f",
         "shirina":100.0,
         "dlina":150.0,
         "image":"",
         "comments":""
      }
   ]
}
```

Пробовал таким образом

```
 private void saveObjectInJson(String name, String width, String height) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("products.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));

        jsonWriter.beginObject();
        jsonWriter.name("id").value(new Random().nextInt());
        jsonWriter.name("name_product").value(name);
        jsonWriter.name("shirina").value(height);
        jsonWriter.name("dlina").value(width);
        jsonWriter.name("image").value("");
        jsonWriter.name("comments").value("");
        jsonWriter.endObject();

        outputStream.close();

    }
```

Но ничего не записало, к тому же, после такой записи не могу прочитать json

Comment: Я вот очень сомневаюсь, что с помощью beginObject можно просто так взять и дозаписать в файл. Вы скорее всего тупо пишете объект уже после самого JSON, поэтому и открытье его уже не можете. Чтобы проверить это, нужно посмотреть в текстовом виде, что вы там записываете в файл. А правильное добавление в массив скорее всего будет - прочитать весь JSON, а дальше либо распарсить его как объекты, добавить новый объект в список, записать JSON, либо уже вырезать последние две }}, сделать как вы сделали у себя и потом добавить снова эти }} с помощью endObject

Comment: Покажите код метода `openFileOutput`, вы там в конструктор `FileOutputStream` вторым параметром что передаёте?

Comment: Мне думается что надо закрывать `jsonWriter.close();` вместо `outputStream.close();` после записи. И проще, наверное добавить всё в `JSONObject`, получить из него строку `JSONObject.toString()` и записать её в файл, если нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли

```
jsonWriter.beginArray();
[...]
jsonWriter.endArray();
```

Comment: После внесения данных правок ничего не изменилось. Я по-прежнему не могу прочитать файл после записи.

Comment: @АндрейСулыз вы хоть напишите, как читаете. Мы не знаем этого. И да, после записи, что в файле, если редактором открыть?